# Trouble with pandas df.values and np.apply_along_axis

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, row, iteration

I need to iterate over the rows of a pandas dataframe. Since "native pandas" iteration is fairly slow due to the creation of a Series object for every row, I decided to iterate over the underlying ndarray rows.

Pseudo-code to illustrate procedure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

store = pd.HDFStore('example.h5')
df = pandas.store[name]
df = df[10:20]
result = np.apply_along_axis(mapped_function, axis=1, arr=df[['colA', 'colC', 'colG']].values)
```

The problem is the somewhat unpredictably, I **occasionally** get errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Example User\My Documents\Example Directory\modul
e1.py", line 15, in <module>
    module2.main()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Example User\My Documents\Example Directory\dir1\module2.py", line 183, in main
    result = np.apply_along_axis(mapped_function, axis=1, arr=df[['colA', 'colC', 'colG']].values)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 129, in app
ly_along_axis
    outarr[tuple(i.tolist())] = res
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 7 to array axis with dimension 11
```

In my case this error occurs either after mapping row 13 or before mapping row 14. In any case, `mapped_function` is never executed with row 14 as arguments but fails before.

If however I change `df = df[10:20]` to `df = df[13:20]` in above code, the offending row goes through for the same data!

Also, if I avoid `apply_along_axis` altogether and do a python iteration, everything works just fine as well:

```
result = []
for row in df = df[10:20]:
    result += [mapped_function(row)]
```

It thus appears, that the `mapped_function`is not at fault but that somehow `apply_along_axis` seems to be experiencing hickups. Unfortunately I have had not luck diagnosing the cause...

Has anybody encountered this issue before?

Comment: Well, your function gives less values than it got?

Comment: What does `df[['colA', 'colC', 'colG']].values` look like?  Shape, dtype?

Comment: What's the expected shape of `result`?  Do all `mapped_function(row)` return the same shape?

Comment: It appears, for 2d `arr` that `apply_along_axis` does `outarr[k,:]=mapped_function(arr[k,:])` for the range of `k`.  The shape of `outarr` is determined by `mapped_function(arr[0,:])`.